# Google pay isReadyToPay method return false

Tags: java, android, google-pay

I am using Google Pay isReadyToPay method always returns false. When does method returns false or true? Is Google Pay connected to the Locale? Thank you beforehand!!!

```
mPaymentsClient = Wallet.getPaymentsClient(activity,
                new Wallet.WalletOptions
                        .Builder()
                        .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                        .build());

    IsReadyToPayRequest request = IsReadyToPayRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_CARD)
                    .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZED_CARD)
                    .build();
            Task<Boolean> task = mPaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
            task.addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                        public void onComplete(Task<Boolean> task) {
                            try {
                                boolean result =
                                        task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                                if (result == true) {
                                    //show Google as payment option
                                } else {
                                    //hide  Google as payment option
                                }
                            } catch (ApiException exception) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hi Nasimxon. I can't see the allowedCardNetworks property (https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/object#CardParameters) . This property is required, have you included it somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed all the requirements from Google? Have you added these lines to the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
android:value="true" />
```